# Treat column as different type for sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a column of type `varchar` - it needs to be a `float` (not in my hands).

How can I make the SQL engine treat this column as `float` for sorting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select name from tbl order by cast(stringColumn as float)
```