# Cast a column type for sorting in Linq2Sql

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865784/treat-column-as-different-type-for-sorting) a great person gave a option to sort a table with a different casting

It is possible to do it in Linq2Sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work client side if you dont use SQL queries as a string.

For instance (I'm just making up some fields):

```
(from c in db.Customers 
select c).ToList() //ToList executes the query
         .OrderBy(c => c.CreditLimit.ToString())
         .OrderBy(c => double.Parse(c.CustomerId))
         //etc
```

Update: It seems you need to do this server side:

```
context.ExecuteQuery(typeof(TestTable1), "SELECT * FROM 
TestTable1 ORDER BY CAST(Text1 as bigint)");
```

Use a SQL query to obtain your objects since Linq-to-SQL does not support your requirement.

Comment: Error: Method 'Double Parse(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: That's why you do ToList first!

Comment: I don't want to get the full list - it is very large - I want so the casting will occur at the DB engine (at the end of the query I take only 40 rows)

Comment: Then, you need to use Context.ExecuteQuery and build a query using a string, I've updated my answer.

Comment: So you say - there is no option at linq :( - I will check about PLINQO or some different framework